# np.linalg.eig() taking a lot time to run

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Is it normal for the np.linalg.eig() function to take more than 10 minutes to work on a (15000, 15000) matrix? I'm running this on the colab environment with standard runtime.

Comment: If you provided code you've used - Others can easily find out whether there's problem in code or not. Minimal reproducible codes always helps!

Comment: yes, it is slow on huge matrices as yours (15000x15000)

Answer (score 2):

Formaly the algorithm should scale as `O(N^3)` for an N-by-N matrix. So if N takes T time, then 2N takes 2^3T = 8T time, and 10N takes 10^3T = 1000T time. On my old laptop N=1500 takes 3.7 seconds. N=3000 takes 22 seconds, which is not really 2^3 * 3.7 = 29.6, but close enough.

Now 3000 * 5 = 15000, and 22 * 5^3 = 2750 seconds = 46 minutes. So that's the time it should take on my computer. So your computer is faster, but 15 minutes seems ok!

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! Is there any way I can run it faster? Also just fyi, It didn't take 15 mins, in fact, it took a very long time, I said greater than 10 minutes because at the time, it was still running and ten minutes had passed.

Comment: @MalavikaUnnikrishnan If you need all eigenvalues I think the only remedy is more cores. If you need only the `k` smallest or largest eigenvalues there are faster algorithms for that, and numpy probably has them implemented also.

Comment: Another detail that could be important is to make sure that numpy is using a fast linear algebra backend. If you are using python through anaconda then it should be linked to mkl. If you use some system default python it is possible that some default library is used which could slow things down. But it is running on multiple threads right?

Comment: @MalavikaUnnikrishnan If this answered your question, you can click the check-mark to accept it. (An the arrow to up-vote:)